Presented at IEEE, paper accepted but delayed for a year. No clarity. Need advice on next steps
I have presented my research paper at an IEEE conference. It has also been accepted at that respective IEEE conference but the publishing is being delayed. It has almost been a year but they don't provide any clarifications on the issue and just keep delaying the process. Please help with what actions to be taken. The IEEE conference is ICCST 2023 which was held at Defence Institute of Advanced Technology in Pune.

Have you contacted IEEE yet?

Contact the conference organizers. There is an email address on the website.

According to (https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/conhome/10474215/proceeding), it seems all/most of the papers have been published and are available on the IEEE xplore database. Is your paper not in the list?
